# Не работает прокрутка в DataGrid - C# WPF/.NET 4.x

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Я создал проект в WPF C#. Я использовал DataGrid. На DataGrid прокрутка не работает по верху ну она работает по внизу. И несколько строку свойство так: "Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed"

```
// Это просто для примера
List<DataGridRow> list = new List<DataGridRow>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (i % 4 != 0)
    {
        list.Add(new DataGridRow()
        {
            Item = new useful()
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                Value1 = "Value1",
                Value2 = "Value2",
                Value3 = "Value3",
                Value4 = "Value4",
                Value5 = "Value5"
            },
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
        });
    }
    else
        list.Add(new DataGridRow()
        {
            Item = new useful()
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                Value1 = "Value1",
                Value2 = "Value2",
                Value3 = "Value3",
                Value4 = "Value4",
                Value5 = "Value5"
            },
        });
}
datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

}

Класс useful

```
class useful
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
    public string Value5 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В XAML у DataGrid добавьте свойства:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

И скроллинг должен появится

Comment: Спасибо, ну там проблема другом. Если вам не трудно, пожалуйста вы не могли проверите сами проверите этот код.Там плохо работают стрелка клавиатуры и прокрутка.